# Modbus Pulse Coils with Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, modbus, modbus-tcp

Have to implement call to ***Digital IO*** with *Modbus protocol* on ***Spring Boot*** project build by ***Maven***.

It should be a pulsed call with some duration at the body (like 5 seconds, etc.)

Here is a snippet from the specification:

[image]

And more about Response and Errors:

[image]

Seems at this call application should behave like a master. And Web Relay should be like a slave in this case.

I suppose that taking some library for integrating with Modbus will be much more preferable than writing it from zero.

***Which approach will be preferable to adopt this functionality with Spring Boot?***

Here are [Web Relay manuals](https://www.controlbyweb.com/webrelay-10/manuals.html).

---

**UPDATE:**

Tried [answer by KevinHerron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66266404/1498427)

Here is the code part:

```
@Override
public void callDigitalIO(String ipAddress, String relay) {
    log.debug("call Digital IO by MODBUS");
    checkNotEmpty(ipAddress, relay);

    ModbusTcpMasterConfig config = new ModbusTcpMasterConfig.Builder(ipAddress).build();
    ModbusTcpMaster master = new ModbusTcpMaster(config);
    master.connect();

    ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.buffer();
    buffer.writeInt(0x00003F00);
    buffer.writeInt(0x000040A0);

    int relayNum = Integer.parseInt(relay);
    WriteMultipleRegistersRequest request = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(
            relayNum,
            0x02 * relayNum,
            buffer
    );

    log.debug("MODBUS_REQUEST: {}", request);

    master.sendRequest(request, 0xFF)
            .whenCompleteAsync((response, ex) -> {
                if (response != null) {
                    log.info("MODBUS_RESPONSE: {}", response);
                } else {
                    log.error("EXECUTION_FAILED: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
            });

    master.disconnect();
}
```

Tried below snippet with a real device, the output is following:

```
2021-02-25 22-07-03.955 [carpark-ex-4] DEBUG c.s.s.dio.ModbusDigitalIoServiceImpl - MODBUS_REQUEST: WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 8, cap: 256))
2021-02-25 22-07-03.970 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] ERROR c.s.s.dio.ModbusDigitalIoServiceImpl - EXECUTION_FAILED: not connected
java.lang.Exception: not connected
    at com.digitalpetri.netty.fsm.ChannelFsmFactory.lambda$null$2(ChannelFsmFactory.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Only when I did:

> master.sendRequest(request, 0xFF).get()

it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy to accomplish using an existing library that supports the WriteMultipleRegisters function.

Try https://github.com/digitalpetri/modbus

---

An example of how to construct a WriteMultipleRegisters request based on that screenshot of documentation:

```java
class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ModbusTcpMasterConfig config = new ModbusTcpMasterConfig.Builder("ip_or_hostname").build();
    ModbusTcpMaster master = new ModbusTcpMaster(config);

    master.connect().get();

    ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.buffer();
    buffer.writeInt(0x00003F00);
    buffer.writeInt(0x000040A0);

    WriteMultipleRegistersRequest request = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(
        0x16,
        0x04,
        buffer
    );

    master.sendRequest(request, 0xFF).get();
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain more details about this call? Have it should be done, is it possible to set timeout to it

Comment: Updated. Time for you to start experimenting. Write code and try it out.

Comment: could you help to understand meaning of `unitId`?

Comment: It's in the spec. It's called slave id when it's Modbus over serial. Your device documentation mentions just using 0xFF, which is commonly used when talking directly to the server and not to a slave behind a gateway. See https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf

Comment: could you clarify one more place - `Pulse Duration (4 bytes, per relay): 0x3DCCCCCC – 0x47A8C000 (Little-endian Format: 0xCCCC3DCC – 0xC00047A8)` - how exactly this duration should be set depends on relay number?

Comment: Those docs suggest you can write to one or more contiguous relays, and you would include one or more 4-byte pulse durations to match.

Comment: tried this approach with real device and it failed. Updated the question with stacktrace.

Comment: Ah, you have to call connect() first on the master.

Comment: surrounded sending request with `connect()` and `disconnect()` with `whenComplete()` it didn't work, but with `get()` works fine. Why did this happen?

Comment: `connect()` and `disconnect()` are async. They return a `CompletableFuture` that you should call `get()` on to block until the action is complete. Otherwise you would need to do the next set of actions in a callback instead.

Comment: You should also not `disconnect()` until after your response has been received.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229254/discussion-between-catch23-and-kevin-herron).